# How to fix the value of the redirect_uri when using the Gmail API?

Tags: python, gmail, gmail-api

I'm trying to access my Gmail Email through their API in order to automate the classification of my Emails but I can't fix the value of the redirect_uri to http://localhost:8080/...

I've tried adding this value to my secret.json file and setting the value of OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT to 1 in my IDEA config file but the value of the redirect_uri is always on a different port when executing the code.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have a video that shows you how to fix the issue https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHz1Rs6lZHQ remember your app needs to be configured to run a static port.

Comment: Welcome to stack please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: Thanks for answering @LindaLawton-DaImTo but I've already configured my Web app on the Google console, my problem is when executing my Python script it always generates a redirect_uri with another port number and therefore get rejected

Comment: The library picks up the redirect URI from your app.   Adding it to console just says its a valid one.  Fix your app